# Is there any good method to disable Mouse/Keyboard wakeup?

Tags: arch-linux, acpi

Is there any decent/universal/best practice method to disable system wakeup from mouse movement or keyboard touch.

This is the output I get from `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP2      S4    *disabled
GPP3      S4    *disabled
GPP4      S4    *disabled
GPP5      S4    *disabled
GPP6      S4    *disabled
GPP7      S4    *disabled
GPP8      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.1
GPP9      S4    *disabled
GPPA      S4    *disabled
GPPB      S4    *disabled
GPPC      S4    *disabled
GPPD      S4    *disabled
GPPE      S4    *disabled
GPPF      S4    *disabled
GP10      S4    *disabled
GP11      S4    *disabled
GP12      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
GP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:2f:00.3
GP30      S4    *disabled
GP31      S4    *disabled
BXBR      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.
```

This list doesn't give any indication which of these is mouse or keyboard and ACPI device code doesn't help me with that either.

I can disable these with `echo 'device_code' > /proc/acpi/wakeup`, but that would mean that I have to test each enabled ACPI device, and that would have to be done on each computer I work with especially if they have a different motherboard or different devices connected.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to operate at BIOS/EFI level